# mysqldump under windows 7 powershell converted all my utf-8 string to latin1 or something alike

Tags: utf-8, mysql

i just did a plain old mysql dump with something like this

```
mysqldump -h "192.168.0.6" -uroot -p db_name > my_sexy_dump_file.sql.
```

What happened is that dumping the database produced a file where all my utf-8 string were converted to latin1. at least it seems to me that that was done cause now i have 2 letters for each one i had previously.
the result looks like this:

╘┐╒Ñ╒╢╒┐╓Ç╒╕╒╢╒í╒»╒í╒╢ ╒ú╓Ç╒í╒╜╒Ñ╒╢╒╡╒í╒»

╘╗╒╢╒Ñ╒»╒╕╒ó╒í╒╢╒»╒╕╓é╒┤

the original text was armenian.

how can i fix this? executing the dump file produces an error. copy and pasting insert queries  into an mysql client application like sqlyog just writes the corrupted string into the table.

Comment: Which mysql version do you use? Maybe add `--default-character-set=utf8` helps?

Comment: it doesn't help when restoring the db from the dump :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by creating a map of the whole alphabet and replacing all corrupted characters one by one.
more details on what i did here: http://fictionalrealm.com/coding/2011/05/29/mysqldump-corrupted-utf8-data-when-dumping-on-windows-machine/

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it to avoid losing charset information:

1. Consider using the `-r` flag to mysqldump so you don't have to pipe the output through stdout->stdin
2. Make sure you use the `--set-charset` flag (or `--opt`) so the dump file contains a `SET NAMES` command.
3. Import using the `SOURCE filename` command.

---

Here's my full dump script (for Bash since I don't run Windows, but you can probably get some good stuff out of them):

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                             
# Version 2.6                                                                           
# Dump a database to file, to be used in migration or as a backup                       
# Emil Vikstrom 2009-2010                                                    

DB="$1";
FILENAME="$DB.$(date -I)"
TMP="$FILENAME.sql"
I=1
while [ -e "$TMP" ] || [ -e "$TMP.gz" ]; do
        let I=$I+1
        TMP="$FILENAME.$I.sql"
done
FILENAME="$TMP"

echo "[$(date +%R)] Dumping..."
mysqldump --single-transaction --hex-blob --add-drop-table --opt -e --quick --quote-names -r "$FILENAME" "$DB"
echo "[$(date +%R)] Compressing..."
gzip "$FILENAME"
echo "[$(date +%R)] Done: $FILENAME.gz"
```

And here's a matching import script:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                             
# Import a database SQL file                                                            
# Emil Vikstrom 2008                                                         
# Version 2.1                                                                           

DUMPFILE="$1"
DATABASE="$2"

if [[ $DUMPFILE =~ "(.*)\.gz"  ]]; then
        if [ -e $DUMPFILE ]; then
                echo "[$(date +%R)] Unzipping..."
                gunzip "$DUMPFILE"
        fi
        DUMPFILE="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
fi

echo "[$(date +%R)] Importing $DUMPFILE..."
echo "SOURCE $DUMPFILE;" | mysql "$DATABASE"
echo "[$(date +%R)] Done"
```

Comment: if i did use the -r during dumping the database the file would have been saved correctly. But i didn't. and now i need a way to convert it into something usable :)

Comment: You can try to force loading it as UTF-8 by adding `SET NAMES 'utf-8';` at the start of the file. Note however that you may have lost data.

Comment: @Yervand: You can't dump the database again?

Comment: i fixed it already ) i made a character by character map o the text. and sis a replace in the file. the dumbest fix ever possible. . . . but at least it works :D more details here: http://fictionalrealm.com/coding/2011/05/29/mysqldump-corrupted-utf8-data-when-dumping-on-windows-machine/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a bit more complicated when dealing with dumps via powershell. If you have iconv you can try fixing the encoding with something like this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\iconv.exe" -f ISO-10646-UCS-2 -t 437//TRANSLIT "D:\all-db-dump.sql" > "D:\out.sql"
```

As instructed here: http://devmd.com/r/fixing-corrupt-mysql-dumps-windows-10-power-shell